# Why is react-top-loading-bar by visible while coming back after its progress reaches 100

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-top-loading-bar for my application like this:

```js
<LoadingBar
    color="#007bff"
    progress={this.state.progress}
    onLoaderFinished={() => this.setProgress(0)}
/>
```

setProgress:

```js
setProgress = (progress: number) => {
    this.setState({ progress: progress });
};
```

When I set the progress to 100, it fades away for half a second and is visible while coming back to zero. What is the reason for this? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, are you saying you wanna show loader even though it's 100%?

Comment: no, what happens is that the loader is still visible after it reaches 100%. It is visible going back to 0%.